# How to store user for many application in same sql database?

Tags: sql

I have three applications (it can be grow) and they use same database (mysql).

All those applications must have login.

So my question is which approach is database normiliztion?

One: creates `user` table for each application. `user-app1`, `user-app2`, `user-app3`. but its create a lot of tables (is it okay?)

Two: create `user` table once and column to indicate which app is authorize role: `app1, app3`. (but its create the same user for all the applications)

Or should I do in a different way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a separate user table for each application would generally be the wrong thing to do.  This approach would duplicate the same data (i.e. user information) across different tables.

In fact, what you would do is have *two* tables:

- `Users`
- `UserApplications`

The first would have one row per user.  It would have all the information about the users -- name, date the user is created and so on.

The second would have one row per user and application the user has signed up for.  It would have additional information, such as the date they signed up for that application.

This allows you to both extend the number of users quite easily and to extend the number of applications (or to remove application).

Answer (score 2):

The best way to evaluate this is to see whether

1. Knowing data about your user from one application differs from the other
2. Will these users use multiple applications together

If users will have 80-90% similar properties e.g. email, name, password hash, etc. and you expect them not to change then approach 2 works best. If you also expect these users to use multiple of these applications then it's definitely 2.

If users will have very different properties i.e. some users for app1 don't have emails but app2 needs emails and some users for app2 don't have names but app1 needs names then you might want to keep them in separate tables for data cleanliness.